# How to optimize for F1 score and prediction speed with randomsearchcv?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, prediction

I am working on a model that is going to run on end users computer in real time. Therefore, prediction speed of the model is critical.

What I already have is a `RandomSearchCV` that optimizes for F1 score.

What is missing is somehow incorporating precision speed into the decision what is the best model.

```
 model = SVC()
 rand_list = {"C": stats.uniform(0.1, 10000),
              "kernel": ["rbf", "poly"],
              "gamma": stats.uniform(0.01, 100)}

 rand_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions = rand_list, 
                                  n_iter = 20, n_jobs = 5, cv = 5,
                                  scoring = "f1", refit=True)

 rand_search.fit(X_tr_val, y_tr_val)  #todo: adjust
 print("Validation score of best model: ", rand_search.best_score_)
 print("Best parameters: ", rand_search.best_params_)
```

What I would want the randomsearch to do is for each parameter combination to run a prediction to check how fast it is. Then give a score based on a mix of f1 and speed.

Pseudo code:

```
def scoringFunc:
     score = f1 + SpeedOfThePrediction
     return score

rand_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions = rand_list, 
                                 n_iter = 200, n_jobs = 5, cv = 5, 
                                 scoring = scoringFunc, refit=True)
```

Does somebody have an idea how I could use prediction speed in my scoring for `RandomizedSearchCV`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two reason why implementing this idea becomes hard,

1. f1- score would be in the range of `[0-1]` whereas your so called  `SpeedOfThePrediction` would be in larger range. Hence just summation would loose the influence of f1-score.
2. The scoring method, which is provided in `RandomSearchCV` just passes the `(y_true, y_pred)` as the input parameter of the scoring function. Hence you cannot compute the computation time/ `speedofThePrediction` inside the scoring method.

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions), sample custom scoring function:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
>>> from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
>>> # A sample toy binary classification dataset
>>> X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_classes=2, random_state=0)
>>> svm = LinearSVC(random_state=0)
>>> def tn(y_true, y_pred): return confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0, 0]
>>> def fp(y_true, y_pred): return confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[0, 1]
>>> def fn(y_true, y_pred): return confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[1, 0]
>>> def tp(y_true, y_pred): return confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)[1, 1]
>>> scoring = {'tp': make_scorer(tp), 'tn': make_scorer(tn),
...            'fp': make_scorer(fp), 'fn': make_scorer(fn)}
>>> cv_results = cross_validate(svm.fit(X, y), X, y,
...                             scoring=scoring, cv=5)
>>> # Getting the test set true positive scores
>>> print(cv_results['test_tp'])  
[10  9  8  7  8]
>>> # Getting the test set false negative scores
>>> print(cv_results['test_fn'])  
[0 1 2 3 2]
```

Comment: I actually figured out a solution. See below. Though Im not sure how well it works on other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this:

```
def f1SpeedScore(clf, X_val, y_true):   
     time_bef_pred = time.time()
     y_pred = clf.predict(X_val)
     time_aft_pred = time.time()
     pred_speed = time_aft_pred - time_bef_pred
     n = len(y_true)
     speed_one_sample = pred_speed / n

     speed_penalty = (speed_one_sample * 1000) * 0.01 #0.01 score penality per millisecond 
     f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred)

     score = f1 - speed_penalty

     return score


     rand_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model, param_distributions = rand_list, 
                                      n_iter = iterations, n_jobs = threads, cv = splits, 
                                      scoring = f1SpeedScore, refit=True, verbose = verbose)
```

It slows things down a little cause you gotta run an extra prediciton. However, as you are just interested in calculating the approximate speed, you could run the prediction on a very small fraction of the dataset to speed up the computation.